# Add text area in google map rectangle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How we add a text area in google map polygon triangle?
We can draw polygon by drawing tools or by onclick event on map but how we show something in rectangle?

And when we move rectangle then our textarea must be moved, Means this textarea must be related to polygon.

I know we draw triangle by this example:-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-event

Comment: Why i get negative point? I don't know this that's why i ask?

Comment: at zoom 0 the rectangle in the linked example would have an approximate size of 0x0 pixels....for which purposes would you need a textarea with a size of 0x0?

Comment: Ya, It's totally in rectangle. if zoom level is 0 then text area size must be 0. @Dr.Molle